# Quits Kernel during evaluation of CreateTopologies

Tags: packages, feyncalc

I am using Feynarts 3.9 and FeynCalc 9.0.1 with *Mathematica* 10. Every time I load FeynArts with FeynCalc and execute

```
t = CreateTopologies[1, 1 -> 2];
```

mathematica quits the kernel after a few seconds.

```
t = CreateTopologies[0, 1 -> 2];
```

works fine.

Can't understand what's wrong. I'm really a beginner at *Mathematica*.

Comment: In fact anything other than 
t = CreateTopologies[0, 1 -> 2];
makes Mathematica quit the kernel. More particles, loops, anything. No idea what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried perhaps a FeynCalc-specific forum? You might have more luck there, since your question probably depends on the packages and not on Mathematica directly.

Comment: Could it be that you are using Mathematica 10.1? I remember having encountered a similar problem with precisely this version on Linux. This problem was not present in Mathematica 10.0.2 and also disappeared when Mathematica 10.2 was released. It's also interesting that for me the console version always worked, while the frontend almost always crashed the kernel. I suppose that it was something wrong in Mathematica that got fixed in the subsequent release and I never investigated it further.

Comment: "I'm really a beginner at *Mathematica*"  Watch [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUHjJ91-nf0TawdfDnOHZBkqJv3D8xly5) nice YouTube videos on Mathematica and FeynCalc.